# How do I complete this partial fraction

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I am trying to take perform a partial fraction decomposition on the following function but something is not correct.$$Y(x)=\frac{(5x+10)(\cos x)}{x^2(x+9+i)(x+9-i)}$$ that I am trying to take the partial fraction decomposition of but something is not correct.

So far, I have $$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x+9-i} + \frac{D}{x+9+i}$$ but if I try to evaluate for $$\frac{A}{x}$$ by doing xY(x), x=0, then I get undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: Where did the cosine disappear in the second expression?

Comment: @Moo yes it is.

Comment: @MattiP. I was just doing the initial setup in the second expression.

Comment: Can you please explain how you did that? Or point me in the right direction?

Comment: $$\frac{5\cdot x+10}{x^{2}\cdot \left(x+9+i\right)\cdot \left(x+9-i\right)}=\frac{-\frac{115}{6724}+\frac{1445 \,i}{6724}}{x+9-i}-\frac{\frac{115}{6724}+\frac{1445 \,i}{6724}}{x+9+i}+\frac{5}{41 x^{2}}+\frac{115}{3362 x}$$